# Getting multiple elements from a list by a list of indexes

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to select some elements from a string list given a list of indexes. For example:

```
String=['a','b','c']
Id = [1,2]
s = String [Id]
```

It gives the error :

> list indexes must be integers or slices, not list.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: what do you want to get? `['b', 'c']`?

Comment: you can only index by 1 index, for a list of indexes you need to get a list back. for a continuous stretch of indexes read about slicing, for discontinued you could construct a new list containing only those indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
String=['a','b','c']
Id = [1,2]
s = [String[id] for id in Id]
```